# Laplacian pyramid reconstruction

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I've been recently studying laplacian pyramids. [image]

Above you can find the original image. I take this image, construct Laplacian pyramid of 6 levels and reconstruct it back again and this is what I get:

[image]

One can notice the reconstructed image is bit "shinier" than the original one. Can somebody explain me why?

Please find the code I used beneath:

```
Mat ** LaplacianPyramid::buildLaplacianPyramid(const Mat& originalImage, int levels) {
Mat ** laplacianPyramid = new Mat*[levels];
Mat * currentImg = new Mat(originalImage);
for (int l = 0; l<levels - 1; l++) {
    Mat * up  = new Mat;
    Mat * down = new Mat;
    pyrDown(*currentImg, *down);
    pyrUp(*down, *up, currentImg -> size());


    Mat * lap = new Mat((*currentImg) - (*up));

    laplacianPyramid[l] = lap;

    currentImg->release();
    up->release();
    delete currentImg;
    delete up;
    currentImg = down;
}
laplacianPyramid[levels - 1] = currentImg;
return laplacianPyramid;
```

}

For the reconstruction I've been using following snippet:

```
Mat * LaplacianPyramid::reconstructImage() {

Mat * currentImg = ( (_laplacianPyramid[_levels - 1]));
for (int l = _levels - 2; l >= 0; l--) {
    Mat up;

    pyrUp(*currentImg, up, _laplacianPyramid[l] ->size());

    delete currentImg;
    currentImg =new Mat( up + (*_laplacianPyramid[l]));
}
return currentImg;
```

}

Is it possible to get precision loss reconstruction? Thanks!

Comment: Are you originally a Java programmer ? Your use of `new` everywhere is extremely scary.

Comment: Yes I am, I know there is a room to improve and this just an adhoc code to play around - far away from a production one

Comment: For your image, I would say the "shininess" comes from the reconstruction being blurred. The dark parts of the original image become lighter and the light ones become darker. To measure this loss of contrast, one classic solution is to compute the [PSNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) between your two images. Bear in mind that PSNR is just an indication and its worth is very debated these days.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say img1 = pyrDown(img), img2 = pyrUp(img1), lap= img - img2. Does this mean pyrUp(img1) + lap != img? Or simply that I have a bug in my code?

Comment: If you are using `CV_8UC3` images, there might be numerical imprecisions in `pyrDown` and `pyrUp`

Comment: May be it is due to the precision loss induced by input data type i.e. `uint8`. Can you confirm if the same is happening if the input data type of your image is `float`.

Comment: Thanks @Sunreef and sparizvi, your suggestion worked. I changed the encoding of the Mat (currentImg) to CV_32F. This has resolved the precision loss issue however now I need 12 bytes to encode the pixel instead of 3. Can you think of any other way how to resolve the precision loss issue and still keep the byte per pixel consumption low?

Comment: Try scaling the grey values in each level before converting to 8 bit. That might reduce the precision lost, if that is actually the issue. But are you sure the pyramid levels need no negative values? I don't know what pyrDown does, but the Laplacian needs a signed result. How about storing as signed int16?

Comment: Thanks Cris. I tried your approach and I can confirm it's correct as well (saves 50% of the memory). I will read into the literature why actually laplacian needs the signed result as it's just a difference of the original and downed / uped image which shall have lower intensities, right? Can you eventually explain?

Answer (score 0):

The "shininess" you're talking about is loss of resolution, actually. pyrDown function down samples the original image to a lower resolution. When Pyrup is called the lost information is tried to be rebuilt using some interpolation techniques. And interpolation of a certain pixel is based on the neighboring pixels.